# Optimizing MySQL Query With MAX(), GROUP BY en ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

Is there any way I can optimize this query to run faster.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT MAX(datum) AS maxdatum
       FROM forumtext
       GROUP BY id_forumtops
       ORDER BY maxdatum DESC
       LIMIT 10


id  select_type table       type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref     rows    Extra 
1   SIMPLE      forumtext   index   NULL            datum_2 8       NULL    283037  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I don't know how to improve the performance in this query further. I know that it is slow because I am using MAX() and that has no index. Is there something else I can do to prevent it from slowing down the query?

UPDATE
@Marcus, I have created a multi-column index on id_forumtops and datum, in that order. It isn't quite faster...

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key             key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  forumtext   index   NULL            id_forumtops_2  8       NULL    283070  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: Here you can see some nice explanation http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT` isn't helping the performance much here because MySQL has to calculate the max values, then sort them, before it can apply the limit. Basically, you're only saving bandwidth.

Probably the only optimization you can do for the query is provide a covering index that speeds up the `GROUP BY` and reading the values. Create a multi-column index on `id_forumtops` and `datum`, in that order.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't quite faster. I think I have to 'cheat' and create an additional field last_post_date in table forumtopics and update it when a new post is posted in table forumtext.

Comment: @Marianne, can you post the EXPLAIN result after adding the above index. Also, you might have to hint MySQL to use it.

Comment: I have posted the EXPLAIN above. I don't understand what you mean with 'to hint MySQL to use it'.